# c# Word-Interop: How to get text after Find.Execute

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

It must be a very easy question, but I can't find the answer since 2 days:
I'm executing a regular expression Find.Execute, and want to get the found text.

The 'execute', and 'while' work correctly.
But I don't get how to extract the found text.

```
IopW.Find f = SetRegEx(wordDoc.Content, @"(\<[A-Z]?@\>)");
while (f.Execute(Replace: IopW.WdReplace.wdReplaceNone))
{
    zeile++;
        // Found correctly!
        // So how do I get the found text now???
        //rng.SetRange(f.Start, f.End);  is not definied
        //rng.SetRange(f.Parent.Start, f.Parent.End); bringt den gesamten Text
        //txt = wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text; // remains empty
        //rng.SetRange(f.FoundText.Start, f.FoundText.End); does not exist
        //txt = f.FoundText does not exist
        // ... ?
    var foundTxt = ????   <== Help pls!!
    Log( zeile + " = " + foundTxt);
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days more of seraching and trying I got the solution.

```
var foundtext = f.Parent.Text;
```

That easy! :-/

(solved)